# IBM Integration Bus has error 'The import path ... cannot be resolved.' that prevents creation of BAR file

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

In a project I have a line that looks something like at the start of the esql files written by previous developers.

```
BROKER SCHEMA com.mypath.esb.local
PATH com.mypath.esb.core;
```

I am new to IBM service bus but had to make changes to some of the esql and make BAR files of them for deployment. For two of the projects I followed the instructions left for me and created the BAR files successfully. For the third I got an error. I noticed one of the esql files in the project (not the one I edited weirdly), had an error:

`The import path com.mypath.esb.core cannot be resolved.` with the line number of the error matching the second line above.

It looks like the library is successfully connected to the project, indeed other esql files in the project start with those same two lines and have no errors.

How do I solve this?

Comment: I have answered my own question because I have found a solution, but remain unsatisfied as to why that works. I will mark a fuller answer as accepted if someone can provide one.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I fixed this by copying over the broken line with an identical line from another file. I thought maybe there was a typo in the original? But no, I undid the copy/paste and yet the error is still gone.

I am assuming that IBM Service Bus needs the line it thinks has an error to be edited in some way before it can clear the error, even if the error should no longer be there.

I have noticed the same error appear on some other projects, so I have tested my own solution. Sometimes the error disappears on paste, sometimes I need to hit 'save' (`ctrl-s`) first, but in all cases this works.